# Reference range in multiple tabs of a different workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to reference the same range within multiple different tabs of another workbook within an index(match,match) setup.

I essentially want the 'Tab_name" below to reference text within a cell that represents a tab name in the other workbook..

```
     index('[workbook.xlsx]Tab_name'!$A$1:$C$5,match(....),match(....))
```

So for example in cell X1 I have the text 'Sheet 1'. I want 'Sheet 1' to appear in the above formula in the place of 'Tab_name'. this would then be repeated for many more tabs for which I am doing the lookup (so cell x1 though x10 would have 10 different tab names in the other workbook).

I have tried the following:

```
  index("'[workbook.xlsx]"&X1&"'!$A$1:$C$5",match(....),match(....))
```

and

```
INDIRECT("'[" & A2 & "]" & A3 & "'!" & A4)
```

where A2 is the workbook name, A3 the tab name, and A4 the range
I then reference the cell containing the indirect formula within my index.

for ease of simplicity I excluded the match(...) syntax but it would follow the same idea I am using for the index.

Neither method appears to work....I have reviewed documentation on the indirect formula and from what I read it looks like this is possible but I am having trouble implementing.

Comment: Can you detail what values `A3` and `A4` have? You can also use the "Evaluate Formula" to step through what values its populating before parsing the `INDIRECT`. What error message are you getting as a result of your formula?

Comment: Is the workbook open?  `INDIRECT` only works with external workbooks if they are open.  Also, does that sheet name has a space in it?  If so, you want to wrap it with single quotes.  Finally, I would test the string you generate for the range outside of the `INDIRECT` to verify it is a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put them in an array like below?

```
=index(sheet1:sheet10!$B$1:$B$10,MATCH(C1,sheet1:sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,0))
```

Notice where I have sheets named there is a : between all of them.